# Getting persistence in a chat system implemented with message queues

Tags: architecture, erlang, message-queue

Me and my team have implemented a rudimentary chat system using a message queue known as [Fubar](http://github.com/refuge/fubar) in Erlang. One of the major requirements on this system is to be able to retrieve chat history, so this needs to be persisted somewhere along the line.

So the problem is this: how would you, in a general sense, hook into this system so as to store the chat messages in a database for later retrieval?

One solution is to have some kind of chat logger process that subscribes to all chats and just stores all messages. This would be a very sensitive spot, a single point of failure -- so architecture-wise perhaps not the best idea.

Another solution is to have some kind of proxy between the message queue servers and the clients that scoops up the messages as they pass.

We're interested to hear your ideas!

Comment: Unfortunately the variety of techniques to do this is pretty large, and without knowing anything more specific about the system I can only give a general "this way, or that way, or another way -- it depends" sort of answer.

Answer (score 4):

The history database is, at a minimum, a single point of failure unless you go to the trouble of multi-master replication, which is its own little mission. Unless you are managing millions of messages per second you should be fine with a logging process that subscribes to chats and pushes them to the db.

But what if you *do* have millions of messages and you've set things up to have a single logging process subscribe to all chats? That is, at a minimum, at least not a favorable situation. Another unfavorable element is the idea that a single DB table would have a bajillion lines of chat messages in it with no partitioning scheme whatsoever. Clearly some partitioning of the problem is in order.

I would probably go instead with one logging process per channel, and on the database side have a db partition per channel as well -- so retrieval can be fast per channel, but you could still write a query that retrieves by date or user globally. Depending on how your database is set up you could further partition the database by date (which puts a limit on how expensive new writes to indexes will get) and if you wind up requiring multiple database masters due to load you can now cleanly partition masters by channel as well (or use three or more, for example: one as foreign master for registration/user data, another as foreign master for channels A-M, and a third as foreign master for channels N-Z or whatever).

With that in mind, if your data is not inherently relational it may be sufficient to stay within Erlang entirely for the database requirements and either use Mnesia or ETS/DETS for your persistent storage of messages. There is nothing inherently relational about chat data, so this might be the smoothest solution of them all. If you do have a genuinely relational backend external to the chat system (maybe chat is just one aspect of the services you provide), it may be best to leave things that way in the larger system, put chat history in Mnesia/ETS/DETS and write an enforcement check that syncs the chat system user data with the canonical relational db.

In any case, the real issue is partitioning, and one-logger-per-channel and one db partition (at least, more likely one partition per channel per month) gives you a good starting place to aggregate partitions into chunks you can manage in a sane way. Also note that this sort of partitioning in code and data allows you to spread the problem out across hardware and erlang nodes, so a crash in any one place will only interrupt whatever channels and logging were running there -- leaving other nodes available to resurrect the affected channels quickly, and sync the data partitions later without encountering a major "who is in charge" sort of problem (netsplits are still something you'll need to write code for, though).

Comment: Good point with the table sharding! We're looking at CouchDB at the moment but it might be a good idea to cut down on the amount of moving parts in the system. There won't be a bajillion messages per second, but there will certainly be quite a lot - it's for an existing semi-popular service.

Comment: @lericson In this case I would treat a crash as a temporary catastrophe, letting live messages that haven't reached a target (or the logger) disappear, but anything that has hit the logger already be on disk somewhere -- so DETS for logs, but have a daily/hourly/monthly/ArbitrarySize rotation scheme where the old log process that owns the DETS table you've logged to up to that point stop taking requests, and save/transfer its data to some warehouse for old logs, while a new process picks up in its stead (make the transition block -- which worst case is as long as a process spawn if done well).

Comment: @lericson As long as the disk you've written to doesn't catch fire (which is why you have a decent data solution somewhere anyway, right?) logs can be reassembled later in the worst outage case, and under normal operation are a seamless chat log history. Unless you're Google or Facebook netsplits should be rare enough that an alarm should trigger human intervention (so you can write a crash/restart of selected nodes utility instead of *actual* consensus code). The fewer gee-whiz utilities the better in my view; I'd stick with dead simple data modeling for a chat log service.